# realign controls inside a layout in NiGui

Tags: nim-lang

I am new to `Nim` and `NiGui`. It seems that `NiGui` does not have a grid container. So I decided to write one for It. The grid can have either fixed or varying number of rows and columns. Creating such a container is not very hard, but sometimes it is needed to replace a `control` with another at a specific row and column. In doing so, I have to be able to change position of controls inside vertical or horizontal layouts as well. NiGui seems to have functions `realignChildControls` and `setPosition` for that purpose. I tried them, but so far no success. I was wondering how could that be achieved without creating another layout and repopulate it with the old one. It worth mentioning a layout has a property `childControls` that contains all controls inside that container. It is of sequence `(seq[control])` type. I think it could have been manipulated easily, but I think they made it immutable. since that converting immutable to mutable seems far reaching, I was wondering how could I change order of controls in a much simpler manner?
Also I could not find a simple way to put an image inside a container alongside other controls, so I wrote a `proc` that makes it simpler and share it in the code as well.

```
import nigui

proc imgWidget(img: Image, size: array[2,int]): Control =
    var ctrl = newControl()
    ctrl.setSize(size[0],size[1])
    ctrl.onDraw = proc (event: DrawEvent) =
        let canvas = event.control.canvas
        canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    ctrl.widthMode = WidthMode_Static
    ctrl.heightMode = HeightMode_Static
    ctrl.onMouseButtonDown = proc (event: MouseEvent) =
        echo(event.button, " (", event.x, ", ", event.y, ")")
    return ctrl

app.init()

var
    window = newWindow("hello")
    maincontainer = newLayoutContainer(Layout_vertical)
    layout = newLayoutContainer(Layout_vertical)
    user_label = newLabel("Username")
    user = newTextBox()
    password = newTextBox()
    password_label = newLabel("Password")
    login = newButton("Log in")
    clear_form = newButton("Clear Form")
    textarea = newTextArea()
    img = newImage()
 
img.loadFromFile("1.jpg")
var img2 = imgWidget(img,[200,200])

login.onClick = proc(event:ClickEvent) =
    textarea.addLine("pressed")  

layout.add(img2)
layout.add(user_label)
layout.add(user)
layout.add(password_label)
layout.add(password)
layout.add(login)
layout.add(clear_form)
layout.add(textarea)

var emptycontrol = newButton("empty")

layout.remove(layout.childControls[2])
layout.add(emptycontrol)
var control = layout.childControls[layout.childControls.len-1]
control.setPosition(0,0)
#layout.realignChildControls()# [layout.childControls.len-1].setPosition(1,2)

maincontainer.add(layout)
window.add(maincontainer)

window.show()
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this question was answered by the maintainer of the NiGui library:

> Reordering of widgets is not yet supported other than rebuilding the
> list.
>
> There is no grid layout. You can use multiple horizontal and
> vertical containers.
>
> NiGui is written in Nim only, but it needs to
> call into WinAPI/Gtk libraries to make windows/widgets.

See Issue 151 https://github.com/simonkrauter/NiGui/issues/151 for further details.